# How to find username from id in telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

I wanted to know that can I find the username of a public telegram channel from it's public id in telethon?

I tried the get_entity method but it is only working for telegram group not channel.

So, how can I get the username ?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 channel=-100XXXXXXX
 result = client(functions.channels.GetFullChannelRequest(
    channel=channel
  ))
  print(result.chats[0].username)
```

channel id should start with -100.

To find the username of a public channel using channel id, You should be a member of that particular public channel.

But, In public Channels, You can see the username in their link https://t.me/channel_username. You don't have to be a member of a channel, to see the username.